# Why does OpenSemaphore always return zero in 64-bit Windows 7 when CreateSemaphore works?

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-7, 64-bit, semaphore

I ported my appliction from Windows 7 32-bit to Windows 7 64-bit. I find that the API function `OpenSemaphore` is always returning zero. This call works well in 32-bit Windows, but not in 64-bit Windows.

When I call `GetLastError()`, it returns 2.

Also I replaced my `OpenSemaphore` with the `CreateSemaphore` function and my application works fine, but I am still confused about why the `OpenSemaphore` function is failing in 64-bit code.

Can anyone who knows something about this issue please clarify?

Comment: Could you provide a minimal code snippet which reproduces the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Checking the error code when a function fails is a good first step, but you need to make sure you understand what that error code means. The possible error codes returned by the [`GetLastError` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679360.aspx) are documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681381.aspx).

In this case, you say that the error code is 2. That corresponds to `ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`, which means

> The system cannot find the file specified.

You are probably asking yourself: file, what file? Yeah, sometimes understanding the error codes requires a little bit of creative thought. So let's think about it: what could "file not found" possibly mean with regard to the [`OpenSemaphore` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684326.aspx)? Well, one of the parameters is a string that specifies the name of the semaphore to be opened. That's *sort of* like a file, right? Close enough to be a good lead!

Chances are, then, the value you're specifying for the `lpName` parameter does not correspond to a valid semaphore. The first thing I'd normally check is the case of the string—the comparisons made with the `lpName` value are case-sensitive. But since you said it used to work in a 32-bit application, that's probably not what's wrong here.

The 32-to-64-bit transition does give us another clue, though. Remember that 32-bit and 64-bit applications are very different beasts and are not generally allowed to touch each other. It stands to reason, then, that a 64-bit application would be unable to use a semaphore created by a 32-bit application, and vice versa.

Considering you said that it works if you call [`CreateSemaphore`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682438.aspx) to create a *new* semaphore, that puts us well on our way to finding an answer. Chances are, the semaphore you're trying to open with the call to the `OpenSemaphore` function is one created by a 32-bit process, and it therefore can't be opened or used by a 64-bit process. (Remember, the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684326.aspx) tells us that *"The function succeeds only if some process has already created the semaphore by using the `CreateSemaphore` function"*.) If you create a *new* semaphore in the 64-bit process, you can open and use it without a problem.

Answer (score 1):

OpenSemaphore and CreateSemaphore are two different things. Open Semaphore is only usable if a semaphore already exists.

from MSDN

> OpenSemaphore function enables multiple processes to open handles of the same semaphore object. The function succeeds only if some process has already created the semaphore by using the CreateSemaphore

Comment: Indeed, there is an important difference between `OpenSemaphore` (which can *only* open an existing semaphore handle), and `CreateSemaphore` (which can both create a new semaphore and open an existing semaphore handle, if one exists). But I doubt the problem is that there's a show-stopping bug in the `OpenSemaphore` function that still lingers in 64-bit Windows, despite having been fixed in 32-bit Windows. And what would that bug even be? It seems more likely to me that the semaphore he's trying to open just hasn't been created yet.

Comment: Yes it is more likely that it is another bug in the application caused be the 32-64 migration than a bug in the Win API of course

Comment: It is beyond reasonable belief that there could be any bugs in the Windows semaphore implementation, whether named or not.  If there were, I would be amazed if any Windows OS anywhere ever got near to the logon screen without exploding in a shower of BSOD.